# Отправка фото с камеры IOS на форму сайта

Tags: javascript, python, django, ios, изображения

Нужно в форму сайта добавить кнопку "Сделать фото" (IOS устройсво), при нажатии на которую открывается приложение камеры устройста, делается фото и отправляется в форму.
Опционально еще можно добавить функционал подтверждения изображения или возможности сделать новое фото, если не понравится.

Желательно какую-то библитеку JS.
Сайт на Django. Вряд ли это имеет большое значение, но на всякий случай напишу.

Comment: И чем не подходит стандартный <input type=file>?

Comment: Точно, не часто пользуюсь этим функционалом на телефоне. Думал, там список файлов только открывается)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так можно открыть камеру и получить изображение для загрузки на сервер

```html
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно - сразу открывается камера, а не список файлов + запуск самой камеры